# how to set width of text widget in tkinter to get text widget equal to length of line

Tags: python, tkinter, text, widget, width

This problem drives me crazy as it looks trivial but i have already wasted many hours to find a solution but still no success. I need help.

Let's say the line is 'HelloHelloHelloHelloHello', the font is Georgia 17. How to find a correct value for the width to get the width of the text widget equal to the length of line? "The width of the widget in characters (not pixels!), measured according to the current font size." My findings show that people asking similar questions get answers about using font measure method, but it doesnt work...

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.font as tkFont

txt='HelloHelloHelloHelloHello'

root=tkinter.Tk()

t_Font = tkFont.Font(family='Georgia', size=17)
width=t_Font.measure(txt)

t=tkinter.Text(root,width=width,font=('Georgia',17))
t.insert(1.0,txt)
t.pack()
```

The result is ridiculous http://joxi.net/E2p1NJlT7NgjvA.jpg (with width=280). Empirical research shows that 20 is a correct value..but how to get it? Using len(txt) looks much better but i believe there should be a good solution. Can't understand what I am missing here...

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `Text` widget having width in pixels around the width of the text, you can put the `Text` widget inside a frame and set the size (in pixels) of the frame to the desired value and then use `.place()` on the `Text` widget to fill the frame:

```py
t_Font = tkFont.Font(family='Georgia', size=17)
width, height = t_Font.measure(txt), t_Font.metrics('linespace')
print(width, height)

lines = 20
# +4 to include the width of the border (default 1) and padding (default 1)
frame = tkinter.Frame(root, width=width+4, height=lines*height+4)
frame.pack()

# put text box inside the frame
t = tkinter.Text(frame, font=t_Font)
t.insert(1.0, txt)
t.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1) # fill the available space of the frame
```

Comment: wow, tnx, kind of surprised that solution is not so easy as i expected